# C++ How do I replace part of a string?

Tags: c++

I am currently working through some uni tasks and I have one where the first task is for the user to input a name which will be inserted into the string. The second task is for the user to input another name which will replace the name which was previously in the string. How do I go about doing this?

This is the code of what I have so far (mostly for task 1, sorry that it's a bit messy/beginner level)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string testString1 = "Do you know who loves C++, XX does!";
    std::string testString2 = "Do you know who loves C++, XX does!";
    std::string name;
    std::string name2;

    std::cout << "Please enter a name" << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, name);    
    
    testString1.insert(28, name, 0, name.length());
    std::cout << testString1 << std::endl;

    testString2.replace(27, 2, name);
    std::cout << testString2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Please enter another name." << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, name2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: read (looks like done), find to get position, then replace using that position.

Comment: @MarekR How would I go about saying how many characters to replace though, as the original name could be different lengths each time the program is run?

Comment: @LuciellePenguin9 well isn't that the same problem you are already facing? What happens if you try to replace `XX` with `Mark`? You already use `name.length()` the first time you insert the name so why not use it again?

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm not sure how to find the name once it's in the string though, I'm pretty sure I need to replace the first name with the second rather than just using the original string again. The name could be different everytime so I don't think I can just use the .find() as it would be for a specific name/length? I'm sorry if I've misunderstood what you said

Comment: @LuciellePenguin9 When doing the second replace, you can start by finding the position of the name (std::string::find), then using that position and the names length replace it with the new name.

Comment: Alternatively, for the code you shown you don't even need to search. The first character of the name is always going to be in the same position, no matter how long or short the name is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, regex should help:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string testString1 = "Do you know who loves C++, XX does!"; 
    std::string name;
    std::string name2;

    std::cout << "Please enter a name" << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, name);    
    
    testString1.insert(28, name, 0, name.length());
    std::cout << testString1 << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Please enter another name" << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, name2);    
    
    testString1 = std::regex_replace(testString1, std::regex(name), name2);
    std::cout << testString1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using input as regex... :/ see [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I don't know about efficiency though, just need to get the job done here.

Comment: I meant, if user input "name" like "[MyNickName]" or other special char, you might have bad surprise.